# Google Sign In with Firebase not displaying the emails to choose from

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I'm trying to implement Google sign in with Firebase to my app (Im new to android studio). It's working, but the popup where it should say "choose your account" and lets you choose between all your accounts from that phone or add a new one isn't appearing. It automatically logs in and uses my main account without letting me choose.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;
    private final static int RC_SIGN_IN = 123;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if(user != null){
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Profile.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        createRequest();

        findViewById(R.id.googleSignIn).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                signIn();
            }
        });
    }

    private void createRequest() {
        // Configure Google Sign In
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken("MY_SECRET_CLIENT_ID")
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

        mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);
    }

    private void signIn() {
        Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
            try {
                // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
                GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
                firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account.getIdToken());
            } catch (ApiException e) {
                // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
                Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(String idToken) {
        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(idToken, null);
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Profile.class);
                            startActivity(intent);

                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Auth Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you are using Java, this article [How to create a clean Firebase authentication using MVVM?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-a-clean-firebase-authentication-using-mvvm-37f9b8eb7336) will definitely help. If you understand Kotlin and you want to learn how Jetpack Compose works, please check this article, [How to handle Firebase Authentication in clean architecture using Jetpack Compose?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-handle-firebase-authentication-in-clean-architecture-using-jetpack-compose-e9929c0e31f8).

Comment: Besides that, have you tried to [sign the user out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69758096/firebase-realtime-database-log-out-google-account) each time you want to sign in again?

Answer (score 0):

Please use revokeAccess() Method

```
private void createRequest() {
    // Configure Google Sign In
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken("MY_SECRET_CLIENT_ID")
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

    mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);
    **mGoogleSignInClient.revokeAccess()**
}
```